# Utilizando expressões regulares com colchetes

Tags: php, regex

Saudações, tenho que retirar qualquer ocorrência de textos entre colchetes. Como por exemplo:

Ex.:  [Texto entre colchetes] Texto fora do colchetes. A saída seria: "Texto fora do colchetes";

Tentei utilizar a seguinte Regex:

```
$string = "[Texto entre colchetes] Texto fora do colchetes";
$String = preg_replace("[\/(.*?)\]/",'',$string);
echo $string;
```

Porém não obtive sucesso.

Comment: Os colchetes são parte da construção de uma expressão regular. Se deseja tê-la na *string*, você precisará escapá-las.

Answer (score 3):

Tente assim (já remove os espaços antes ou depois dos colchetes):

```
$string = "[Texto entre colchetes] Texto fora do colchetes";
$String = preg_replace("\s*\[.*?\]\s*",'',$string);
echo $string;
```

`\s` remove espaços em branco seguido do `*` para pegar mais de um.

`\[`e `\]` escapa o caractere `[` e `]` pois o regex o utiliza.

O resto está igual o que você inseriu na pergunta.

Answer (score 3):

Basta anular os colchetes com o caracter de escape (`\`) e dizer que uma ou mais ocorrências devem ser subsituidas com `+`.

Essa expressão regular vai falhar em casos onde a string está mal formatada, por exemplo: `[texto dentro] texto fora]]]]`

```
$string = "[Texto entre colchetes] Texto fora do colchetes [outro texto] [[asdfasdf]]";
$novo = preg_replace("/\[+[\w\s]+\]+/i",'',$string);
echo $novo;
```

Resultado:

```
Entrda: [Texto entre colchetes] Texto fora do colchetes [outro texto] [[asdfasdf]]
Saída:  Texto fora do colchetes
```

[Exemplo - ideone](https://ideone.com/Gp7wAR)

Answer (score 1):

Segue a expressão regular para resolver seu problema e use [trim()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.trim.php) para remover espaços.
Veja um exemplo funcionando [aqui](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8834270b0b6fae5cb1440ca5e12a293991bc21e6).

```
$string = "[Texto entre colchetes] Texto fora do colchetes";

echo trim(preg_replace('#\s*\[.+\]\s*#U', ' ', $string));
```